# How can I programatically retrieve performance data (CPU, memory usage) of an Azure Cloud Service?

Tags: c#, azure, performancecounter, azure-cloud-services

I'm looking for a way to retrieve performance data of an Azure cloud service. Specifically, I need CPU and memory usage statistics of the last 5/30/60 minutes.

Googling around I found that this can be done by accessing Azure's default performance counters, but the documentation seems to be scarce and ambiguous as to how to do this programatically. Also, I need to do this without making any manual configurations to the service after the deployment.

Anybody got any idea?

Best regards,
Remus

Answer (score 0):

Ideas? Yes. Will it fit your use case? I do not really know. What do you need to do with the data?

Have you thought about integrating Application Insights: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-US/documentation/articles/app-insights-cloudservices/ It allows collecting (custom) performance counters telemetry (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-US/documentation/articles/app-insights-cloudservices/#performance-counters).

If you not only need to see/monitor these counters you can enable continuous export to a sql database and collect the data in code from there. You can also define alerts based on certain values.

They are also working on a Rest API so you could get the raw data from there for further processing, see https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/357324-application-insights/suggestions/4999529-make-data-accessible-via-apis-for-custom-processin.

Might be a bit overkill to use AI for your specific scenarios however, since you only need it for the last hour.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the KUDU API to get the CPU and Memory usage of your w3wp processes that running in your cloud service.
To access the KUDU service from browser type - https://[your-web-site-name].scm.azurewebsites.net.
Their you can see in the Process explorer tab the CPU and Memory information about the w3wp processes.
If you want to do it programtically you can build http client and access the data, for example - 
GET https://[your-web-site-name].scm.azurewebsites.net/api/processes/  - To get all processes.
GET https://[your-web-site-name].scm.azurewebsites.net/api/processes/[proccess number] - to access each process and get the information.
For credentials you need to look in your publish profile - and get the userName and userPWD.

A nice example can be found - 
http://chriskirby.net/blog/running-your-azure-webjobs-with-the-kudu-api

Comment: The question was about Cloud Services, not App Service.